# delete the number one by one from vector after every 30 seconds input taken from console

Tags: c++

I want to delete the after every 30 seconds of the current time and the input should be taken form console.So After deletion of 1st number, after 30 sec 2nd number should be deleted

```
 #include <time.h>
 #include <vector>
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main ()
{

int input,sec1;
vector<int> v;
while(cin >> input){
v.push_back(input);
}
time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;
time ( &rawtime );
timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
int sec = timeinfo->tm_sec;
 cout<<sec<<endl;
 //sec1 = sec+30;
 for(int j=sec; j<=60; j=j+30){
 for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){
 v.erase(v.begin() +i );
 cout<<v[i]<<endl;
 }

 }

  cout<<sec<<endl;

    for(int i = 0; i<v.size(); i++){

  cout<< v[i] <<endl;
  }
   return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hum..

To answer your main problem, you can use in C++11 the thread library like that.

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    std::vector<int> v(1000);
    std::iota(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 0);  

    for (int i=0;i<v.size();i++) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        std::cout << v.size() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Nowwww... 
To erase your vector you did pretty wrong.
Erase actually remove the element from the vector. so after remove your first element (position 0), erase will shift the remaining element and your iterator will jump to element one, thus you will erase half your vector!

Comment: I understand it, but I need a more explanation regarding thread and how it delete the number after 30 sec.